# Extjs 6 How to use Promise in Proxy?

Tags: extjs, proxy

I use a external library to fetch some data. To get some data I just type:

```
this.service.query(...args)
```

It returns a Promise<[]>.

What kind of a Exta.data.proxy.Proxy I should extend/use?

I don't want fetch date before and then create a Store with a memory proxy.

Answer (score 0):

There is no functional `proxy` for your needs, but in my opinion you should extend a [Ext.data.proxy.Server](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/classic/Ext.data.proxy.Server.html).

You must override `doRequest` function.
See `Ext.data.proxy.Ajax` for example (which is based on `Ext.data.proxy.Server`).

Answer (score -1):

You can use a Ext.ajax.request, it returns a promise which you can use to create a store using Ext.create and store.loadData

Comment: He said in question : `I don't want fetch date before and then create a Store`